# how I can change permission for a folder in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have jenkins working in local server on my mac and for a job, I need to run a script shell witch it need to read a json file. I tryied to put it in workflow-lib file. But when I run the job for testing, the script return an error witch says :

```
/Users/****/.jenkins/workflow-libs/testCollections: Permission denied
Build step 'Run a shell script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

So I know that the script can read the json file but I don't know how I can give it this permission. 
thank you for helping

Comment: are you running jenkins using new jenkins user or urself?

Comment: I am using it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow this command to give the permissions.

```
sudo chown -R <jenkins user>:<jenkins group> /jenkins_root_path
```

here `<jenkins user>` and `jenkins group` is the user and group which you are running jenkins under.

Answer (score 0):

If the `jenkins user` is a member in the `sudoers` list:

```sh
sudo rm -rf /Users/****/.jenkins/workflow-libs/testCollections
```

But this can be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest you run the Jenkins process as the jenkins user/group and not muck around in there as your own user account.

This will ensure your file permissions are proper and that the jenkins process only has access to the areas it needs as well as letting you spin up new slaves without worrying about permissions and custom settings.

You can always use sudo to become the 'jenkins' user to work with the files.